# Метод загружает дефолтные значения DbSet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

В проекте имеететя страница Game.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<BlackJack.Models.Player>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Game";
}

<h2>Game is started!</h2>


<body>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Shuffle", "Player"))
  {
    <input value="Shuffle" type="submit" />
  }
  <table>
    @foreach (var p in Model)
    {
      {
        <tr>
          <td><p>@p.Id</p></td>
          <td><p>@p.Name</p></td>
          <td><p>@p.Count </p></td>
        </tr>
      }
    }
  </table>
</body>
```

При нажатии кнопки Shuffle переходит в метод

```
public ViewResult Shuffle()
{
  foreach(var p in playerDb.Players)
  {
    p.Count += (int)GetRandomCards();
  }
  return View("Game",playerDb.Players);
}
```

Каждый раз при нажатии Shuffle Count каждого объекта playerDb.Player должен суммироватся, но каждый раз значения объектов playerDb.Player в методе дефолтные.

playersDb - объект класса PlayerContext, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class PlayerContext : DbContext
{
        public PlayerContext() : base("PlayerContext")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Так вы в базу не сохраняте изменения через `SaveChanges()` а во вью передаёте результат чтения из базы. Вот уже ответ есть, принимайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ViewResult Shuffle()
{
  foreach(var p in playerDb.Players)
  {
    p.Count += (int)GetRandomCards();
  }
  playerDb.SaveChanges(); // !!!
  return View("Game",playerDb.Players);
}
```

Comment: Теперь появился второй вопрос: как при загрузке приложения вернуть дефолтные значения?

Comment: Кхм, кхм. Хранить их в поле `CountDefault` и в каком-то месте вызывать `p.Count = p.CountDefault;`, наверное.

Comment: Я создал следующий метод:                                                                                            
 private void DefaultCount()
        {
            foreach(var p in playerDb.Players)
            {
                p.Count = 0;
            }

            playerDb.SaveChanges();
        } и вызвал его из конструктора моего контроллера, но изначальная проблемма опять вернулась

Comment: @НазарМазурик Конструктор контроллера вызывается на каждый запрос. Вы же говорили о "загрузке приложения".